# Remove solution class library reference from .net core 1.0 project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-core-1.0

I've added a reference to a class library to .net core project, now I am not sure how to remove it? See attached screenshot.

[image: class library references]

I would like to remove GeoDomain library but context menu does not offer that ability, nor does clicking on Del key do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some head banging, it seems that to remove reference you have to click on `Add Reference...` and uncheck box of the project you wish to remove. Go figure!

Answer (score 1):

In the Projects.Json try to remove the packages which are not restored properly.